# How to run Liclipse/Pydev debugger over internet?

Tags: python, django, pydev

I have a remote development Linux machine (with own IP address) in a VPS provider. I also have my machine that connects to internet via a router. I want a Django process in the server to connect to a pydev debug server on my machine.

I use pydev debugger, this configuration tells django at any host to connect to the given host/port where the debugger is running.

```
pydevd.settrace('localhost', port=5678, suspend=False)
```

How to connect to the VPS from my desktop? NAT is impossible since the router and DHCP is not in my control. VPN seems feasible but complicated.

Answer (score 0):

I think the best way to resolve it in this case would be doing a port forwarding through ssh -- I don't have any specific instructions for that, but google has plenty ;)